# Как правильно пользоваться Time.deltatime при работе с RigidBody2D.velocity

Tags: unity3d

Есть код:

```
float deltaX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
float movement = deltaX * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
rb.velocity = new Vector2(movement, rb.velocity.y);
```

По идее теперь количество кадров не должно влиять на скорость движения обьекта. Но если запустить приложение не в 60 кадрах, а в 30, то обьект двигается в 2 раза быстрее. Аналогично если запустить в 120 кадрах, то обьект двигается в 2 раза медленее. В чем ошибка?

=====================================================

Кстати, обьект двигается с одинаковой скоростью при разной частоте кадров,  если написать код вот таким образом:

```
float deltaX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
float movement = deltaX * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
rb.velocity = new Vector2(movement, rb.velocity.y);
```

Но коректно ли использовать Time.**fixedDeltaTime** вместо Time.**DeltaTime**, если вызов идет из **Update()** вместо **FixedUpdate()**?

Comment: никак ей не надо пользоваться

Comment: Документация [Rigidbody.velocity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html) **Note:**  A velocity in Unity is units per second.... это не дистанция шага, она не множется ни на какую дульту времени от слова "совсем". Документация написана что бы её читали, там буквально все что нужно знать. И про `Time.fixedDeltaTime` и про `FixedUpdate` и обо всем тоже можно прочесть в документации, что бы не ошиваться с вопросами подобного рода по интернетам, где какую тока херь не несут, что ровно и происходит на этой странице.

Comment: @Yaroslav то есть в данном конкретном примере, можно просто убрать умножение на Time.deltaTime и скорость всегде будет одинакова независимо от частоты кадров?

Comment: @Yaroslav Я просто пытаюсь разобраться в вопросе всеми доступными для меня способами. Если бы я не задал этот вопрос, то и не получил бы толковый ответ от вас. За что кстати, я вам очень благодарен.

Comment: @Влад, ответ: читайте документацию, без этого вообще никуда, будь у тебя за плечами 3 дня юнити или 3 года, все равно приходится читать документацию. Есть много разных вопросов, но по теме "как работают базовые механизмы юнити", ответ чаще всего один и искать другой это ошибка. Вон, даже LGL ссылается на документацию, хоть и несет ересь, а бывает и хуже.

Comment: @Yaroslav согласен. Я не нашел в документации умножения на дельту, наверное "обучающие" ролики на ютубе, где люди учат писать код именно так - пагубно влияют. Даже книга по которой я учусь "Юнити в действии" от Д.Хокинга учит писать именно так. На данный момент я пришел к выводу, что умножение на Time.fixedDeltaTime не дает ничего так как это фиксированная величина, потому это действие лишь уменьшает скорость. Потому персонаж у меня и двигался одинаково что при 30, что при 120 кадрах после такого умножения. Мои выводы верны? И еще раз спасибо. Отвечаете жестко, но это приносит пользу.

Comment: @Влад, нет не прав, ты перепутал теплое с мягким.